# Execute commands from history that match regex or grep

Tags: bash, grep, command-history

I was wondering if its possible to execute commands from history that match a certain regex? I know you can do something like

```
fc 232 248
```

And it will go into your `history` and then do revisions 232-248 consecutively.

However, if some of the commands in between are things I do not want to do, is there a way I can specify that? Right now I look up my `history` and pipe it out to a `grep`

```
history | grep checkout
```

So this will look up all terminal actions I've done with checkout I have done.

```
232 git checkout master files/file1.txt
234 git checkout master files/file2.txt
248 git checkout master files/file3.txt
```

It filters out some of the numbers so I only want to execute the ones that have been piped out. rather than everything in between

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you would like to run the results of grep as commands again?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it...  Nevertheless, I think what you are trying to do is kind of dangerous - you never know, so imagine the grep command get some lines that you don't want to run, but as the commands will be automatically run you won't have time to correct the errors...

Comment: @cremefraiche Yes correct I think that's a good way of putting it although I'm uncertain if I would need to filter out what is spit out from grep and how I would do that.

Comment: @JIMM This is true but I can simply preview what the grep should spit out so I will know what commands I'll be running.

Answer (score 2):

To execute all commands containing a specific string (e.g. `"checkout"`) or regex (e.g. `"checkout.+file\d"`) from your bash `history`:

```
grep -E "string_exp" $HOME/.bash_history | while read line; do eval "$line"; done
```

You can save this as a function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_prev () {
   grep -E "$1" $HOME/.bash_history | while read line; do eval "$line"; done
}
```

Then in future you can just type:

```
all_prev checkout
```

---

EDIT:

- To avoid running many duplicate commands as your `.bash_history` file accumulates these over time, make sure `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups` is set in `~/.bashrc` if it isn't already.
- To avoid rerunning the `all_prev` search containing the search term each time, use regex `^` and `$` to specify chars at the start and end of the line.

---

However, perhaps you should also check out a shell with more powerful history filtering like [`zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) (or even [`fish`](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/)).

Comment: This would end up running EVERY command in my history that has the word "checkout" in it. Not exactly what I want.

Comment: @aug You could grep for whatever you want using the above command. You don't have to just search for a simple string but that's all you provide in your question. The function could be modified to include an '-E' flag so as regex could be passed as well. See change above.

Comment: @aug e.g. `all_prev "checkout.+file\d"`

Comment: @aug updated answer to avoid duplicate commands running and specify 'searched-for' command more exactly..